# Secondary Monitor Applications Graphically Freezing

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

My installation of Windows 10 has recently started acting oddly (on the secondary monitor only). I don't know exactly when the first time it happened was, but what has been happening is that the graphical display on the secondary monitor will freeze all application interaction. What I mean is that I can move the mouse, and the cursor will properly move about the screen - however, I cannot in any way interact with any application windows that reside on the secondary monitor (or at least it doesn't appear to interact.

Let's say I have a Settings window open on the primary monitor. If I click and drag to move it to secondary, the window just vanishes at the end of the primary monitor. If I drop the window of on the secondary monitor (even though I cannot see it), and close it with keyboard shortcuts, then opening a new Settings window (which reopens on the secondary) doesn't display a new window. I can then Alt+Space, M to move the window using the keyboard back onto the primary monitor, and suddenly I can see it again.

I also found that certain acts (such as starting a UAC prompt) will refresh the image on the secondary monitor (i.e. if there were invisible windows, after the UAC is cleared, the windows become visible, and the same in reverse). The windows (though not visible) still don't refresh or show changes if I attempt to interact with them.

In debugging the issue, I've looked around and found many similar (although 3+ year old) posts on MSDN and other sites, but their answers didn't do anything in my case. Unplugging the secondary and reconnecting it doesn't change anything (except that all the windows work fine since they get bumped of the secondary monitor). Going into settings and switching which display is primary/secondary doesn't do anything (i.e. the issue moves to the display that is "secondary" regardless of which monitor/output is being used).

Interestingly, I tried installing an updated GPU driver since I new an update was published this November (I'll list system specs at the end), and the nVidia installer reported that the OS or hardware was incompatible! Interesting since per [their driver detail page](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/155056#) it isn't...

I'm still working to try to figure out what is happening, but if anyone has any insights or ideas as to what may be causing this, I would appreciate it. From what I recall, the only thing that was done before the issue was changing the Power Options Plan from "Power Saving" or "High Performance".

Added: 
I forgot to include that *usually* restarting the computer will handle the issue for the day (although it doesn't always, and I can't be sure it only lasts for the day).

I also have one Windows update that I'm doing to see if that handles it.

[image: System Specs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure if there was a bug in the previous update done to Windows 10, or if there was something else going on. After doing a couple rounds of Windows Updates, the issue stopped happening, so I'd assume it's something along those lines.

Therefore, the many answer to the issue I was having is (as you'd likely guess) 
**make sure all systems updates are completed!**

The nVidia GeForce update still insists that it is not compatible (which is strange), but it seems to be working, so I'll leave it alone for now.